# mixing c# and html in quick succession

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to build a grid server side, I wrote this in a cshtml file:

```
@{
    var items = (List<FancyItem>)ViewBag.items;
    var col = 0;
    var colMax = 3;

    foreach (var it in items) {
        if (col == 0) {<tr>}



        if (col == 0) {</tr>}
        col++;
        if (col == colMax) {col = 0;}
    }
}
```

So in theory, the column creation code would go in between the two if's, however, I never got that far. The two if's are supposed to create rows when the columns reset but it seems everything after < tr> gets interpreted as plain text. I don't know what to do, what kind of syntax candy would fix this?

Comment: I assume some code is missing here, everything after the `<tr>` gets interpreted as plain text? What does? You mean the actual Razor markup gets interpreted as plain text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your issue - Razor expects you to close any opening tags or it thinks you are still writing HTML

Try this:

Edit: Added `@`s to get the content to write to the HTML output stream

```
foreach (var it in items)
{
    if (col == 0)
    {
        @Html.Raw("<tr>");
    }

    if (col == 0) {
        @Html.Raw("</tr>");
    }
    col++;
    if (col == colMax)
    {
        col = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I also had to put @ in front of the commands, otherwise nothing would make it to the page

Comment: Sorry yeah I had @s in there in the first place and edited for some reason to remove them (I couldn't remember if you needed them or not but you do when you aren't already in an HTML or text node)